# Get notable_type from Freebase Search output

Tags: python, freebase

I'm trying to get the notable type from search results so that, say, when I'm searching for "Helium", I can display "Helium (Chemical Element)" and "Helium (Artist)" as two options to choose from if the search returns multiple things with the same display name.

Right now, I'm able to get the just the raw type like this:

```
service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search'    
params = {
    'query': query,
    'key': FREEBASE_KEY,
    'output': '(topic)'
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
for result in response['result']:
    print result['output']['type']['/type/object/type'][0]['name']
```

But that often gives me a type that's not really what I'm looking for, or something that's still pretty ambiguous/ weird. So I want to get the Notable Type or the Notable For instead of just the raw type.

So when I replace `type` with `notable_type` or `/common/notable_for/display_name` or `/common/topic/notable_for/` in the `'output'` parameter, I get an error because there are no results from my search.

So, how can I get to the Notable Type using output?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct output param is:

```
'output': '(notable)'
```